# Footnote text: 2nd paragraph and subsequent indenting

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

I need to type a few large footnotes containing two or more paragraphs.

I had customized in my preamble the `\@makefntext` command to get my desired footnote text format.

```
\renewcommand\@makefntext{\mbox{\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark\ }}
```

My output currently looks like this, first paragraph is ok, but I'd like to indent the second one:

[image]

The problem is that the previous definition doesn't work with `footmisc` option `\hangfootparskip`.

I would like to get this output:

[image: Desired output]

I've done it manually with `\hspace{1em}`at the beginning of the second paragraph, but I'm searching for a better and cleaner solution.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally, I figured it out myself.

Redefining `\@makefntext`with

```
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]%
{\mbox{\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark\ }}{\setlength\parindent{1em}\noindent#1}}
```

does the trick showed in the second image of my original post.

No need to mess with `footmisc` option `\hangfootparskip`

Here's a compilable .tex in case anyone wants to try it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[stable,bottom]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]%
    {\mbox{\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark\ }}{\setlength\parindent{1em}\noindent#1}}
\makeatother

%\setlength\footnotemargin{0em}
%\renewcommand\hangfootparindent{1em}
%\renewcommand\hangfootparskip{0\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit. Suspendisse
potenti.\footnote{This is a very large footnote.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit. 

Second paragraph correctly indented by 1em. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit.}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit. Suspendisse
potenti.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit.

Second paragraph. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit.

Third paragraph. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit.} 

\end{document}
```

And here is the correct output:

[image]